# Save As and disable formulas and macros

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a VBA code to save as in a map and also turn off all formulas and macros.

This is what I've come up with so far but it isn't working.

```
Sub Opslaanzonderformules()
  Dim strFileName As Variant, strPath As String
  Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject, VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent, CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
  strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=strPath & [AJ2], _
                                              FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls, Excel 2007 Files (*.xlsm), *.xslm", _
                                              FilterIndex:=1, _
                                              Title:="Kies de juiste map en pas eventueel de bestandsnaam aan!")
  If strFileName = False Then
    MsgBox "Oh oh... je hebt niet opgeslagen! "
  Else
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        With .Sheets("blad1")
            .Unprotect
            .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
            .Protect
        End With
     Set VBProj = .VBProject
     For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
            If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
                Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
                With CodeMod
                    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
                End With
            Else
                VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
            End If
        Next VBComp
    .SaveAs Filename:=strFileName
End With
  MsgBox "Gelukt!  Opgeslagen als: " & strFileName

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working?

Comment: I got a error message starting by 'VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject' and I can't find the solution.

Comment: Could you add the full text of the error message and where in the code this occurs? Please add these details to the question. Thanks

Comment: I've got the message "A user- defined data type is not assigned".

Answer (score 1):

If you save the file as `xlsx` then any code is automatcially removed. Which simplifies to:

```
Sub Opslaanzonderformules()
  Dim strFileName As Variant, strPath As String
  Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject, VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent, CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
  strFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=strPath & [AJ2], _
                                              FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls, Excel 2007 Files (*.xlsm), *.xslm", _
                                              FilterIndex:=1, _
                                              Title:="Kies de juiste map en pas eventueel de bestandsnaam aan!")
  If strFileName = False Then
      MsgBox "Oh oh... je hebt niet opgeslagen! "
  Else
      ActiveSheet.Copy
      With ActiveWorkbook
            With .Sheets(1)
               .Unprotect
               .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
               .Protect
            End With
      .SaveAs Left$(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, ".")) & "xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
      End With
  MsgBox "Gelukt!  Opgeslagen als: " & Left$(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, ".")) & "xlsx"
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless more information is provided, my guess is that the reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for applications Extensibility #.#' is not selected in 'Tools'|'References' or manually added in code.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

I copied your code as is, and the code broke on the declaration for VBProj as VBIDE.VBProject. As soon as I referenced the aforementioned reference, the code executed.